# How can I set a git config item as a function?

Tags: bash, passwords, git, github

I'm trying to set up the `gist` gem, but I don't want to have my GitHub password stored as an environment variable or git config item. The [README](https://github.com/defunkt/gist/blob/master/README.markdown#authentication) from the GitHub repo explains,

> You can also define github.password to be a command which returns the actual password on stdout by setting the variable to a command string prefixed with `!`.

The problem I'm having is figuring out where to put the described function. Any tips?

Here's the function described in the above link (fetches github.password item from Mac OS Keychain):

```
password = !security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -gs github.password | ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: \\\"(.*)\\\"$/'
```

Comment: Is this the best forum for this question or would it be better on another SE site? If so, how can I move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line belongs in $HOME/.gitconfig in the `github` section.  Shell escaping and such will make life difficult, so if $HOME/.gitconfig does not exist or if it does not have an `github` section, create it with

```
git config --global github.password foo
```

That will create the file if necessary with the correct formatting and add a line

```
password = foo
```

Edit the file and replace `password = foo` with that recommended on github.

Comment: So it should go in as an alias rather than under the github heading as recommended in the README?

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `alias.github.password`?

Comment: @kopischke You are probably right and github.password is correct.